# Protocol not wroking from container

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I have a `ViewController` with two overlapping `ContainerViews`. And from one of child views i would want to change tab to another.

[image]

I created a protocol:

```
protocol pickerDelegate {
    func changeMainContainer(index:Int)
}
```

In child view:

```
class ChildViewInContainerController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    var delegateStorePicker:storePickerDelegate?
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        self.delegatePicker?.changeMainContainer(0)
    }
}
```

In Main view:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, storePickerDelegate {
    func changeMainContainer(index:Int) {
        switch index {
            case 0 :
                self.container1.hidden = true
                self.container2.hidden = false
            case 1:
                self.container1.hidden = false
                self.container2.hidden = true
            default: break;
        }
    }
}
```

Code works, but changeMainContainer function not been called.

Comment: Where did you assign the delegate?

Comment: In view:  Button In container 1

Comment: That doesn't tell me much. Could you show us the code, e.g. how you create you child views and assigning the delegate.

Comment: According to your shown code, your delegate is `nil`. You only declared it to be a `storePickerDelegate?`. You'll have to assign your main view controller to this delegate or else it will stay `nil`.

Comment: How do i do this ? I used the same code with NavigationController and it works....

Comment: There is a naming confusion `storePickerDelegate` vs `pickerDelegate` and protocols are supposed to start with a capital letter

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with the same code as navigation controller, but as far as I know if you want to use the delegation methods of a navigation controller you'll have to assign the delegate first as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protocol: (notice I changed the protocol conforming `class`)

```
protocol PickerDelegate: class {
    func changeMainContainer(index:Int)
}
```

ChildView: (Changed your delegate to a weak var)

```
class ChildViewInContainerController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    weak var delegateStorePicker: PickerDelegate?
}
```

Main view:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, PickerDelegate {

    // I don't know how you create your view
    func createChild() {
        let controller = ChildViewInContainerController()
        controller.delegateStorePicker = self

        // Your own implementation
    }
}
```

Making the delegate weak prevents a strong reference cycle.